# how to generate the unique random pair in perl?

Tags: perl, random

```
[hard_filters]    
usage=array
arraycount=2
yrsexp=23:24;33:56;54:55;34:35
```

I am trying to read the values from a config file using `Config::Tiny`. So after getting the values `usage`, `arraycount`, `yrsexp`. If the `usage` has the value `array`, based on the arraycount it should generate pairs of min and max:

```
$yrs = "min='23,54',max='24,55'";
```

If `usage` is one not `array`, it should not take the array count. From the `yrsexp` it should select a random single pair.

```
$yrs = "min='33',max='56'";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This short program does what you ask. It uses `shuffle` from the [`List::Util`](https://metacpan.org/module/List%3a%3aUtil) module to randomize the `yrsexp` list before using it. Processing the case where `usage` *isn't* `array` is identical, but with `arraycount` set to 1.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Config::Tiny;
use List::Util 'shuffle';

my $cfg = Config::Tiny->read('config.cfg');

my $hf = $cfg->{hard_filters};
my @yrsexp = shuffle map [ split /:/ ], split /;/, $hf->{yrsexp};

my $count = $hf->{usage} eq 'array' ? $hf->{arraycount} : 1;
my @sample = @yrsexp[0..$count-1];
my $yrs = sprintf "min='%s',max='%s'", 
    join(',', map $_->[0], @sample),
    join(',', map $_->[1], @sample);

print $yrs, "\n";
```

**output**

```
min='33,23',max='56,24'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split the values of yrsexp by the semicolon and then use Perl's **[rand](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/rand.html)** function to randomize through the index.

Something like this:

```
my @years = split ';', $yrs_exp;
my $rand_index = int(rand(scalar @years)); # Returns 0 up to size of @years - 1
my $rand_value = $years[$rand_index];
```

Comment: `my $rand_value = $years[rand @years]`